# odoo one invoice per month for several orders

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo V8.0, I would like to do the following:

We make several sales orders a month for a customer. At the end of the month, we want to make one invoice that contains all the uninvoiced orders, with the all the order lines copied.

I have searched high and low and I know it can be done but I cannot seem to find how.

thank you for your ideas!

EDIT:
We would like to manually initiate the invoicing action, get an overview of everything that is not yet invoiced, select the lines we want invoiced and then 'invoice'

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge I just think that point and categorized your point and try to make that ideas comes in my mind to development flow which I mentioned given Below.

**You should make a one crone job (scheduled action) in Odoo**

---

You have to set the scheduled action perameters

---

- Interval Unit  by months
- next execution date,
- active as True
- Method (name of method which you can set in your py)

and some other parameters which you want to set as per your need

**The scheduled action method logic :**

some thing like this..

```
sale_pool=self.pool.get('sale.order')

sale_line_pool=self.pool.get('sale.order.line')
```

**Filter Record By uninvoiced exists in sale order ids :**

```
sale_ids=sale_pool.search(cr,uid,['&',('invoice_exists','=',False),'&',('date_order','>',your_cur_month_start_date),('date_order','<','your_cur_month_end_date)]
```

**Filter Record By uninvoiced exists in sale order line ids with related sale order only :**

```
order_line_ids=sale_line_pool.search(cr,uid,[('order_id','in',sale_ids)])
```

Then after you can browse that sale order line data and create a new single account invoice based on sale order line.

other wise you can override the **action_invoice_create() method** from the **sale order** and you can do based on your logic

I hope this shold helpful for you .. :)

Comment: Well yes I can see how this is a solution but this is an automated system with the cron job. However, it would be better to initiate the action manually. This way you can indicate exactly which lines to invoice. I will edit the original question.